# GPU Fan really loud, all the time

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, motherboard, power-supply, fan

I have a GTX 560 TI that appears to be stuck at a 100% fan speed all the time. The fan is running extremely fast.
It runs around 25 degrees Celsius, which I would expect for a fan going that fast

Originally I was going to use this card on a windows XP machine running a i3 & 4 GB Ram. (Yes the card is overkill for Windows XP, but it was cheap).

I tried the following without success:

- Using MSI Afterburner
- Air dusting the card and resitting the fan pin header
- Air dusting the sockets and resitting the components of the
  computer
- Motherboard BIOS update to last revision
- Another motherboard
- Different GPU (GT 440) with the same PSU - no fan problems

I bought it off eBay, the seller listed this as having hardly any use and has been sitting in a [HTPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_theater_PC). (I can't imagine why you would consider a card fan speed that fast being suitable for a HTPC).

The only conclusion I have come up with that either the BIOS has been modified to run the graphics fan at that speed (not sure if that is possible), or the temperature sensor is faulty.

Perhaps a GPU bios update might fix it?

Does anyone have experience with these types of cards, should it make that hairdryer noise?

Here is a video with the sound: https://youtu.be/SxJ0XiDI2fU
You occasionally hear a slight variation in the noise (quick and hardly noticeable).

Comment: What is meant by *hardly any use*? Was it sitting in a powered-on HTPC for 5 years and the previous owner just never played anything on it?

Comment: I doubt the BIOS has been modified, that is something that is rarely done and there would be no need in an HTPC... Afterburner shows the GPU  temps are acceptable. It is possible that the fan speed sensor is defective, telling the GPU the fan isn't spinning, or not fast enough, so it's sending full power to the fan. It is noisy, could be the bearings going out in the fan assembly as well.

Comment: @rob. It was said that it was used a couple of times. I would perhaps then assume that the HTPC was plugged in but just off.

Comment: A possibility to consider:  The wire for the speed sensor of the fan is broken inside, even if the outer insulation is still intact.  This will give about the same result as a defective temperature sensor.